# Insert an array into another array in numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do I do this? (in a computationally efficient way)

```
arr1 = np.array([0, 4, 8, 12, 16])
arr2 = np.array([1, 5, 9, 13, 17])
arr3 = np.array([2, 6, 10, 14, 18])
arr4 = np.array([3, 7, 11, 15, 19])

what_i_want = [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly pass a list of arrays to [`np.ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) to flatten in **F**ortran order:

```
np.ravel([arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4], 'F')
```

Slower alternative with `stack` and `ravel`:

```
np.stack([arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4]).ravel('F')
```

output:

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19])
```

Answer (score 2):

using transpose of `np.vstack` and flattening:

```
np.vstack((arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)).T.ravel()
# np.array((arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)).T.ravel()   # alternative way
"""
np.vstack

[[ 0  4  8 12 16]
 [ 1  5  9 13 17]
 [ 2  6 10 14 18]
 [ 3  7 11 15 19]]

np.vstack().T

[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]
 [12 13 14 15]
 [16 17 18 19]]

np.vstack().T.ravel()

[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]
"""
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following:

```
np.array([arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4]).T.reshape(1, -1)[0]
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19])
```

Answer (score 0):

**I think this is the easiest way to reach your goal.**

> ```
> import numpy as np
> arr1 = np.array([0, 4, 8, 12, 16])
> arr2 = np.array([1, 5, 9, 13, 17])
> arr3 = np.array([2, 6, 10, 14, 18])
> arr4 = np.array([3, 7, 11, 15, 19])
> newArray = np.array((arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4)).T.ravel()
> print(newArray)
> ```

***what_you_want:***

*Output :*

> [ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19]

Comment: It is same as my answer.

Comment: yes .quite close. and you explained it very well. @Ali_Sh

Answer (score 0):

```
    #importing dependencies
    import numpy as np
    arr1 = np.array([0, 4, 8, 12, 16])
    arr2 = np.array([1, 5, 9, 13, 17])
    arr3 = np.array([2, 6, 10, 14, 18])
    arr4 = np.array([3, 7, 11, 15, 19])
    #creating an array to store results
    X = []
    #writing a loop to add each element(i) of the arr1,2,3,4 in the result. but                            
    all the arrays must be of the same lenght as are in your case.
    for i in range (0 , len(arr1)):
      X.append(arr1[i])
      X.append(arr2[i])
      X.append(arr3[i])
      X.append(arr4[i])
    print("X = " , X)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `np.concatenate` like this:

```
what_you_want = np.concatenate((arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4))
```

Source:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/absolute_beginners.html#adding-removing-and-sorting-elements

You can also look this:
https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html?highlight=concatenate#numpy.concatenate

Comment: This gives the wrong output, that's why I changed it. @Nesaijn

Comment: So you are saying that the best way to go about doing this is to concatenate the arrays, and then sort the list?

Comment: I misunderstood the result you wanted. My bad. @AriFrid